# Was Dreamfall: The Longest Journey removed from Xbox 360 in UK/EU markets?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, dreamfall-the-longest-journey

I recently bought a new Xbox 360 and recovered my profile.

I started downloading games I hadn't finished before I traded my last console. One of them was Dreamfall: The Longest Journey.

When I tried to download it, an error code came up in Xbox live. I then proceeded to log in to the xbox.com site and attempted to add the title to my download list. That came back with an error saying "Not available in your region".

I've been away from Xbox Live a while. Have they begun to remove games from their catalogue? Is there any way I can get this game on my Xbox other than purchasing it again? I really wanted to finish it.

Edit: I'm in the UK

Comment: What region are you in? I am looking at the American site, and it is still available there for 1200 Points

Comment: I have changed the question to Specify what region i am actually in.

Comment: Thats what happens with digital distribution. Legalized stealing from consumers.

Comment: Not a happy bunny but i do believe ill have to live without :(

This is exactly why i hate digital only downloads :( the ability to erase an objects existance with jsut a keystroke :(

Comment: You might call Xbox Live support and see if there's anything they can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it has been removed, but there has not yet been a reason given to explain why. A high possibility resides on weak sales of the title and the restructuring of Xbox live content since you originaly downloaded it but this is merely speculation - there's no definite answer for you.

If you still had the hard drive you originally installed to, you could still have it otherwise you'll just have to do without.

Hate to be the bearer of bad news.